# How to redirect a URL for example (www.foobar2.com) to another URL (www.foobar.com) using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, url-masking

I am setting up a link which should open another website. For example, if a browser is opening up ***www.foobar2.com***, it should open ***www.foobar.com*** without changing the URL. I found out that it can be done using ***.htaccess*** file. Currently, if I open, ***www.foobar2.com***, it redirects to ***www.foobar.com*** but the URL also changes to ***www.foobar.com***. But I want that URL should not change. What do I need to do?

I tried this which isn't working -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.foobar2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.foobar.com [P]
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks :)

Comment: "I tried this which isn't working" - And what _exactly_ happens? Do you get an error? (That shouldn't trigger an _external redirect_, which you suggest is what does happen.)

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, the code which I provided is working(like it is redirecting from ```foobar2.com``` to ```foobar.com```) but the URL is also changing to ```foobar.com``` but I need that the URL should remain the same as ```foobar2.com```

Comment: Are you in control of `foobar.com` (the destination site)? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have access to the main server config?

Answer (score 1):

Since the http host the request is sent to is always that shown in the URL (for obviousl reasons) you need to implement a proxy feature, this cannot be done using pure rewriting or redirecting.

The apache http server offers a proxy module for this, it can be either used standalone or integrated into the rewriting module. However you want to use it you need to take care that the module is actually loaded first. It consists of *two* submodules, the core proxy module and the proxy_http module in this case.

Now you can implement a `ProxyPass` directive for the URL you want to fetch from the other host:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / https://www.foobar.com
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.foobar.com
```

(yes, that is an `off` in the first line above)

This rule needs to be implemented in the http host `www.foobar2.com`. It will make an internal sub request to `www.foobar.com` for each incoming request (since it masks the root (`/`) and deliver the response it receives back to the originally requesting client.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but it isn't working for me. I am getting ```internal server error(500)``` after trying your supposed solution. Can you please let me know the process step by step?

Comment: Most likely the proxy module is not loaded... You will see a hint on an unsupported command in your http servers error log file.